# How to create a function in postgresql that creates policies on tables

Tags: postgresql, function, policy

I would like to create policies on multiple tables. Since there are many tables and they should all have the same policies (>200) I would like to create a function that I would be able to call.

This is the policy that I'd like to create

```
create policy policy_name on table_name for all to user_name using (column = 'some_value');
```

But since There are many tables I would like to create a function like this:

```
create or replace function add_policy(text, text, text) RETURNS void AS $$
    create policy $1 on table1 for all to $2 using (column = $3);
    create policy $1 on table2 for all to $2 using (column = $3);
    ...
    create policy $1 on tablen for all to $2 using (column = $3);

$$ LANGUAGE SQL
```

I'd like to be able to call it like this:

```
DO $$ BEGIN
    PERFORM add_policy('somepolicyname', 'someusername', 'valuetomatch');
END $$;
```

I've tried multiple versions of this but I just can't find a way to do a `create policy` within function.

Comment: It should be simple with [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).